# How to get td values on radio button selection using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this div below, where on selection of `CFGID` radio button I should be able to get the same rows values. eg: `testDev`, `indi` etc values

```
<div id="updateFormDiv">
        <table class="tableForms">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tableHeading"></th>
                    <th class="tableHeading">Name</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading">Host Name</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading">Description</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading">Type</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading">Last Update Time</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="CFGID" id="CFGID" value="11579"></input></td>
                    <td>testDev</td>
                    <td>indi</td>
                    <td>testDev</td>
                    <td>Development</td>
                    <td>Fri Apr 26 04:31:40 IST 2012</td>                           
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

So on button click I wrote this

```
alert($("input[name='CFGID']:checked").next().text());
```

but it gives me empty. Please help me fetch each values. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
$(document).on('change', ':radio[name="CFGID"]', function () {
    var arOfVals = $(this).parent().nextAll().map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
});
```

`arOfValues` will then be an array such as `['testDev', 'indi', 'testDev', 'Development', 'Fri Apr 26 04:31:40 IST 2012']` (i.e. the text in the remaining columns for that row)

Your selector didn't work because the `<td>`'s which contain the text are `next()` elements on the *parent* of the input, not the `input` itself (the `input` has no siblings).

Note how you can use `$(this)` inside the event handler to refer to the element selected, rather than `$("input[name='CFGID']:checked")`. Also see how I've used event delegation via [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), as binding the same event to multiple elements is poor practise.

Read up on [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on), [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent), [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll), [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to see their uses.

Comment: Radio buttons don't have an `onselect` event.  Shouldn't that be `.on('change'`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var texts = [];

 $("input[id='createRad']:checked").siblings("td").each(function(i, v){
     texts[i] = $(this).text()        
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='CFGID']").on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().nextAll('td').text());
});
```